# How to create an inline / minimal Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's possible, for example, to [use ActiveRecord inline in a Ruby script](https://github.com/c-hive/basics/tree/884229e117a13f0bcbdc8aa34047905726713527/inline-activerecord). I like this a lot to report bugs, test features and share gists.

I'm wondering if the same could be done for a Rails webservice? (I'm mainly interested in getting the controller layer to work, the rest should be easy to add on demand.) Something along these lines:

```
begin
  require "bundler/inline"
rescue LoadError => e
  $stderr.puts "Bundler version 1.10 or later is required. Please update your Bundler"
  raise e
end

gemfile(true) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"

  gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
end

require 'rails/commands'
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('config/application', __dir__)
Rails::Command.invoke('server')
```

When toying around with this it did seem that an external entry point (`APP_PATH`) is required. So alternatively, an acceptable approach would be to cram all config into the single entry point. I couldn't get this to work so far.

[The Rails Initialization Process](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#railties-lib-rails-all-rb) is the best resource I found about this so far.

I produced a minimal Rails app to get started as follows:

```
rails new min-rails --skip-keeps --skip-action-mailer --skip-action-mailbox --skip-action-text --skip-active-record --skip-active-storage --skip-puma --skip-action-cable --skip-sprockets --skip-spring --skip-listen --skip-javascript --skip-turbolinks --skip-test --skip-system-test --skip-bootsnap --api
cd min-rails
rm -rf app/jobs app/models config/initializers config/locales lib log public tmp vendor config/environments/test.rb config/environments/production.rb config/credentials.yml.enc config/master.key bin/rake bin/setup bin/bundle
```

Comment: https://christoph.luppri.ch/articles/rails/single-file-rails-applications-for-fun-and-bug-reporting/ https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2014/2/14/putting-ruby-on-rails-on-a-diet/

Comment: This is great. I'm only wondering how to serve the app created in `Single file Rails applications` so it cannot only be used with a test framework.

Comment: You mean "so it can be used outside of a test framework" ?

Comment: Yes, basically so that I can get a response from localhost:3000.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up with the [following script](https://github.com/c-hive/basics/tree/a986c3cebe0dbef3fcc0ac65e309081a52a6ccbc/inline-rails):

`inline-rails.rb`

```
begin
  require "bundler/inline"
rescue LoadError => e
  $stderr.puts "Bundler version 1.10 or later is required. Please update your Bundler"
  raise e
end

gemfile(true) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"

  gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
end

require "action_controller/railtie"

class App < Rails::Application
  routes.append do
    get "/hello/world" => "hello#world"
  end

  config.consider_all_requests_local = true # display errors
end

class HelloController < ActionController::API
  def world
    render json: {hello: :world}
  end
end

App.initialize!

Rack::Server.new(app: App, Port: 3000).start
```

Run it as:

`ruby inline-rails.rb`